# ASA anyconnect VPN restriction base on group

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vpn, firewall

We have implemented Remote access VPN on ASA and integrate with `onelogin` cloud base `OTP` service, where we have LDAP server and `onelogin` provide RADIUS service to provide LDAP+OTP base authentication.

In my VPN config we just tell use `onelogin` RADIUS for authentication and everything working fine but now if i want to create multiple Group and provide authentication base on group and set ACL, how can i do that?

This is what we have, EMPLOYEE group and now i want to create other group which has only 2 users called CONTRACTOR and i want them not to authenticate using EMPLOYEE profile.

```
aaa-server ONELOGIN (outside) host 201.XX.XX.12
 key *****
 authentication-port 1812
 accounting-port 1813

tunnel-group EMPLOYEE type remote-access
tunnel-group EMPLOYEE general-attributes
 address-pool ANYCONNECT-POOL-EMPLOYEE
 authentication-server-group ONELOGIN
 default-group-policy GroupPolicy_ANYCONNECT-EMPLOYEE
```

## UPDATE

for testing i have installed `freeradius` in my lab and bind with LDAP and here is the sample configuration.

Freeradius config in `post-auth` section

```
if (LDAP-Group == "sales" ) {
    update reply {
                    Class = OU=GroupPolicy_ANYCONNECT-SALES;
                Reply-Message = "You are Accepted"
            }
     }
    elsif (LDAP-Group == "finance" ) {
        update reply {
                    Class = OU=GroupPolicy_ANYCONNECT-FINANCE;
            Reply-Message = "You are Accepted"
        }
    }
    else {
        reject
    }
```

ASA config:

```
group-policy GroupPolicy_ANYCONNECT-SALES internal
group-policy GroupPolicy_ANYCONNECT-SALES attributes
 dns-server value 10.0.0.10 10.0.0.11
 vpn-filter value VPN-FILTER-SALES
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ssl-client
 group-lock value SALES
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value ANYCONNECT-SALES
 default-domain value sales.com
!
!
tunnel-group SALES type remote-access
tunnel-group SALES general-attributes
 address-pool ANYCONNECT-POOL
 authentication-server-group RADIUS
 default-group-policy GroupPolicy_ANYCONNECT-SALES
tunnel-group SALES webvpn-attributes
 group-alias SALES enable
```

I am seeing ASA VPN allowing user A to authenticate in both tunnel, how do i lock down so user A won’t be able to authenticate in Finance and user B won’t be authenticate to Sales, in short user can only authenticate to own group profile.

Comment: If you create a separate tunnel-group for CONTRACTORs then your RADIUS auth will have either the attribute: Cisco-VPN-Tunnel-Group-Name = "CONTRACTOR", or Cisco-VPN-Tunnel-Group-Name = "EMPLOYEE". It will then be up to onelogin to distinguish.

Comment: i will check with `onelogin` vendor,  we have LDAP server in house so can i tell ASA to check `MemberOf` and if it's not part of  group then deny user

Comment: I asked onelogin and they said they have no such feature at preset. :(

Comment: Is there any way i can create local database or userlist and tell asa not allow them to authenticate to `X` group?

Comment: is there any other work around? can i create two web portal on Cisco ASA and one for `contractor.asa.com` and other one `employee.asa.com` ?

Comment: We have something very similar in place; but we use a single aaa configuration and fork the auth within the RADIUS based on the attributes (Cisco-VPN-Tunnel-Group-Name is just an obvious one). The RADIUS then queries both our own LDAP (checking for membership in the appropriate group) and then DUO's LDAP to confirm second factor. The RADIUS then returns a single ACCEPT/DECLINE.

Comment: I have updated my question with new results, I am seeing users still able to access other group profile. how to lock this down?

Comment: I don't know that you can impose a change in groupPolicy by submitting that OU in your radius reply? Instead, we have separate tunnel-groups for each class of user (SALES & ACCOUNTING) with separate group-url and group-alias. Each tunnel-group has a separate default-group-policy (GrpPol_SALES & GrpPol_ACCT). Both tunnel-groups have the same aaa server configured; however, inside radius, the authentication request has different values for Cisco-VPN-Tunnel-Group-Name. I don't know FreeRADIUS, but Radiator allows you to define a "handler" and specify a different LDAP query for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution:

This is what i did on radius, map `TunelGroupName=` ASA attributes with ldap group. and its working now.

/etc/raddb/users

```
DEFAULT Ldap-Group == "cn=sales,cn=groups,cn=compat,dc=example,dc=com", ASA-TunnelGroupName = "SALES"
DEFAULT Ldap-Group == "cn=hr,cn=groups,cn=compat,dc=example,dc=com", ASA-TunnelGroupName = "HR"
```

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: You got that one.

Answer (score 0):

On the ASA, this is regularly achieved through the assignment of different group policies to different users. When LDAP authentication is in use, this can be achieved automatically with an LDAP attribute map. In order to use LDAP to assign a group policy to a user, you must map an LDAP attribute, such as the AD attribute memberOf to the Group-Policy attribute that is understood by the ASA. Once the attribute mapping is established, you must map the attribute value configured on the LDAP server to the name of a group policy on the ASA.

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/91831-mappingsvctovpn.html